# Opening FileChooser Dialog

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

this is my first ever Swing project and I barely know anything related to Java and GUI. After struggling with SWT (Eclipse), I decided to switch to Netbeans for Swing app (I don't want to go for netbeans platform atm). so I might nag you guys a bit while my project is going on.

My first question is how can I open a JFileChooser dialog to select a specific directory? That's what I have done:

**IN SWING DESIGNER MODE**

- Drop text field (made editable false so that user wouldn't input values)
- Drop a button next to it labeled "Browse"
- Now here is the confusion, shall I drop a JFileChooser on the pane? If I do this, then the panel shows Browse dialog all the time ... or shall I create a new JFileChooser on button click event? What is the best practice?

**IMPORTANT**
*The question I am asking is not how to use `JFileChooser`. I am asking how to use it with Swing Designer in Netbeans. When i drop it from the Palette, it is always shown in the designer.*

P.S:
After lots of struggle I decided to go with Swing. I was not even willing to go for Java based GUI but I had not choice because Java has better underlying api for the project I am working on and now building a basic GUI sucks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a confusion I think, the File Chooser you use is from the Swing Window, you can't add or attach this one to a button.

The easiest way to proceed :

> Properties of the button -> Events -> actionPerformed
>
> Add an event (click on the arrow to choose default or `...` to custom the method name
>
> Netbeans will automatically switch to `Source` mode.
>
> Add something like this in the created method :

```
        JFileChooser jfc;
        jfc = new JFileChooser();     
        File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        jfc.setCurrentDirectory(f);
        jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        jfc.showOpenDialog(parentFrame);
        File selFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
```

Answer (score 2):

When you start with Swing, I strongly suggest to read the Swing tutorials. For example the part about the `JFileChooser` you want to use is located [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html). Those tutorials contain heaps of sample code and are a nice addition to the javadoc.

A quick scan of that tutorial did not show the answer to your question, so here the direct link to the javadoc of the method you are searching: [`JFileChooser#setCurrentDirectory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setCurrentDirectory%28java.io.File%29)

Comment: The question i am asking is not how to use `JFileChooser`. I am asking how to use it with Swing Designer in Netbeans. When i drop it from the Palette, it is always shown in the designer.

Comment: Sorry, no experience with NetBeans' Swing Designer.

Answer (score 0):

In the Properties window there is the property *fileSelectionMode* to be set to DIRECTORIES_ONLY. Furthermore you can set *currentDirectory*, *selectedFile*.

BTW GUI under Swing is not at least powerful.

Comment: Can you please READ the question before answering? read the **IMPORTANT** tag in my question.

Comment: Sorry, I feel stupid today. Yes on the button's actionPerformed invoke the JFileChooser. The first time a JFileChooser is a bit slow, so maybe make it a field. In the Navigator you select Other Components and insert from Windows a JFileChooser.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has an accepted answer but If you want to use JFileCHooser from the netbeans design view, goto navigator, right click on other components -> add from palatte. JFileChooser will be added to your panel/frame and you can configure it using the netbeans properties window